# アフィン変化による平行移動で絵の一部が切れる

Tags: java, opencv

アフィン変換で絵を平行移動( tx=30, ty=60 )させたいのですが、平行移動した分絵が切れてしまいます。どうしたら絵が切れなくなりますか。

```
import gab.opencv.*; 
import org.opencv.imgproc.*; 
import org.opencv.core.*; 

OpenCV opencv; 

void setup(){   
    opencv = new OpenCV(this, "sample.png", true);   
    size(500, 300, P2D);   noLoop(); 
} 

void draw(){   
    Mat src_mat = opencv.getColor();   
    Mat dst_mat = new Mat(); 

    Mat skew_x_mat = new Mat(2, 3, CvType.CV_32F);    //(1)   
    float [] tmpmat = {      
        1.0, 0.0, 60,     
        0.0, 1.0, 30,
    };     //(2)   
    skew_x_mat.put(0, 0, tmpmat);      
    Imgproc.warpAffine(src_mat, dst_mat, skew_x_mat, src_mat.size());    //(5)   
    PImage outImg = opencv.getSnapshot(dst_mat);   
    image(outImg, 10, 10); 
}
```

Comment: 括弧 `{ }` の対応が取れていないようですが、プログラムはこれで全部でしょうか？ (閉じ括弧が足りない)

Comment: Processingを使っています。これでは問題なく動いています。